# Shortcut for expanding IEnumerable Results View in Visual Studio debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ienumerable, visual-studio-debugging

When I'm debugging in Visual Studio (up to 2012) and hovering over a variable to explore all the properties, I explicitly need to press the **Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable** button on IEnumerables.

As I am <del>inherintly lazy</del> a superefficient coder I was hoping there was some kind of shortcut, like double clicking or a hotkey. Is there any?

[image: huge distance]

**Update**

@Alex Essilfie has created a suggestion on Uservoice. Follow [this link](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4329630-automatically-populate-ienumerable-results-in-data) to vote it up before the VS2013 release!

Comment: Have you considered creating a [Custom Visualizer](http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2008/06/11/122792.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for your link! That is quite interesting. I might going to try that one day, but it seems a bit much overhead for such a simple request. I.e. whenever I have to switch workspaces I have to reinstall the DLL. Notice the *inherintly lazy* part :)

Comment: @DirkBoer: I put in a suggestion on uservoice. Follow [this link](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4329630-automatically-populate-ienumerable-results-in-data), vote for it, and hopefully we will have something done about it by the time VS2013 is officially released.

Comment: Thanks! You have my three votes ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you have to expand manually when the type implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`. It should be automatic as for `List<T>`

Answer (score 2):

You could install a commercial extension I created for Visual Studio called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com), which enhances the VS debugging experience and replaces Visual Studio's UI for the on-hover DataTip, and since I'm also a super-**lazy** coder, I decided not to require the user to click a separate button before he/she can expand the "Results View" node.

Another solution, which is not really more efficient but does not require using the mouse, is to hit Shift+F9 (to pop up the QuickWatch window) and then type in "cats,results" and then hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a default keyboard shortcut for this in VS, but if you go to Tools/Options then Environment/Keyboard, you can add a shortcut of your own for any command - if you can figure out which one you need...

Comment: "if you can figure out which one you need..." that's the core part of the question of course :) but thanks anyway!